# AES encryption in typescript decryption in Go

Tags: typescript, go, encryption, aes

I'm trying to encrypt data in typescript and take the encryption output the pass it to the decryption function in Go but the output in Go does not match the input in typescript so what is the problem?

This is my typescript code:

```js
import * as CryptoJS from 'crypto-js';
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('7061737323313233');
var iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('7061737323313233');
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("Im new in aes encryption"), key,
    {
        keySize: 128 / 8,
        iv: iv,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
    });

var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key, {
    keySize: 128 / 8,
    iv: iv,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});

console.log('Encrypted :' + encrypted);
console.log('Key :' + encrypted.key);
console.log('Salt :' + encrypted.salt);
console.log('iv :' + encrypted.iv);
console.log('Decrypted : ' + decrypted);
console.log('utf8 = ' + decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

This is my Go code:

```golang
func main() {
    d2, _ := Decrypt("VMlk9qzp2BKZi5wZjlzst2iwEre0uD/VHVc6xm2bhXY=", "37303631373337333233333133323333")
    fmt.Println(d2)
}
// Decrypt decrypts cipher text string into plain text string
func Decrypt(encrypted string, CIPHER_KEY string) (string, error) {
    key := []byte(CIPHER_KEY)
    cipherText, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(encrypted) ////hex.DecodeString(encrypted)

    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if len(cipherText) < aes.BlockSize {
        panic("cipherText too short")
    }
    iv := cipherText[:aes.BlockSize]

    cipherText = cipherText[aes.BlockSize:]
    if len(cipherText)%aes.BlockSize != 0 {
        panic("cipherText is not a multiple of the block size")
    }
    mode := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(block, iv)
    mode.CryptBlocks(cipherText, cipherText)

    cipherText, _ = pkcs7.Pad(cipherText, aes.BlockSize)
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s", cipherText), nil
}
```

Comment: Which pkcs7 you wereusing? I am reproducing it.

Comment: im using this "github.com/mergermarket/go-pkcs7"

Comment: and I don't know the type in ts , but when I search in google I found that it is look like this `padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7` , so if this is the problem I don't know any other way to change it

Comment: 1. use the same key when dec. 2. remove this pad function. Then you could get a string "cryption". I am tring to get the true answer, guessing a problem of iv or pad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please use the same key "7061737323313233".
2. Use the same iv.
3. Dec the full text.

```
func main() {

    d2, err := Decrypt("VMlk9qzp2BKZi5wZjlzst2iwEre0uD/VHVc6xm2bhXY=", "7061737323313233")
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(d2)

}

// Decrypt decrypts cipher text string into plain text string
func Decrypt(encrypted string, CIPHER_KEY string) (string, error) {
    key := []byte(CIPHER_KEY)
    cipherText, _ := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(encrypted) ////hex.DecodeString(encrypted)

    block, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if len(cipherText) < aes.BlockSize {
        panic("cipherText too short")
    }
    // iv := cipherText[:aes.BlockSize]
    iv := []byte("7061737323313233")

    cipherText = cipherText[:]
    if len(cipherText)%aes.BlockSize != 0 {
        panic("cipherText is not a multiple of the block size")
    }

    // cipherText, _ = Pad(cipherText, aes.BlockSize)

    mode := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(block, iv)
    mode.CryptBlocks(cipherText, cipherText)

    return fmt.Sprintf("%s", cipherText), nil
}
```

Comment: And a note, pad the cipher text if needed.

Comment: thanks a lot its works for me but ,could you tell me how I get the `types of pads` in `Go` so I will try it in the future ?? to match it with typescript

Comment: @AlaaRadwan In your case: 1. your source text is 32 bytes, multipul of 16, thus no need to pad. 2. the pad function pads even the text length is multipul of 16. Not a cryptographer, I cannot tell you about `types of pads`, just @me when you have questions in any time.

Comment: @p1gd0g it is necessary to pad the function irrespective of the pad length. If the source is already a multiple of blocksize, another complete block of padding according to the pkcs#7 standard.